# sorting of div data using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I'm trying to sort some DIVS in different ways and I'm quite lost. I've been trying some stuff but I don't see how to get it to work. I have div data in following format. I have a dropdown with sorting options like sort by price, by distance and by creation date etc.. On selecting an optin from dropdown the divs data should be sorted and dispalyed accordingly. Example is I choose sort by price then data should be displayed in sorted order as with price starting from lower to higher.

I need your guidance on this.

```
<div id="contentContainer">
  <div id="content">
      <div>
        <div class="price">120</div>
        <div class="dateDiv">2012-05-09 20:39:38.0</div>
        <div class="distance">20 mile</div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <div class="price">123</div>
        <div class="dateDiv">2012-05-10 20:39:38.0</div>
        <div class="distance">30 mile</div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <div class="price">100</div>
        <div class="dateDiv">2012-05-11 20:39:38.0</div>
        <div class="distance">50 mile</div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <div class="price">124</div>
        <div class="dateDiv">2012-05-12 20:39:38.0</div>
        <div class="distance">60 mile</div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you should use a table, and one of the many jquery plugins available. E.g. http://tablesorter.com/

Comment: @Tim: Yes I understand that but to change this div format and use table format would be very messy I guess as I have lots of css and I have to invest too much time to change div format to table format while retaining the way data is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example to sort by price:

```
$('#content div.price').map(function () {
  // map sort-value and relevant dom-element for easier handling
  return {val: parseFloat($(this).text(), 10), el: this.parentNode};
}).sort(function (a, b) {
  // a simple asc-sort
  return a.val - b.val;
}).map(function () {
  // reduce the list to the actual dom-element
  return this.el;
}).appendTo('#content'); // < inject into parent node
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QmVsD/1/

---

a few notes:

- the first map isn't really needed, but it makes the sorting callback much simpler.
- you would need to supply different compare-callbacs for different data-types (e.g. dates, strings)

Answer (score 0):

What you've got there is actually a TABLE, so use a table and one of the existing table sorters.

There is nothing wring with using `<table>` when you have tabular data, and that's what you've got.

Answer (score 0):

The generated HTML is part of the *presentation*, while the sorting operation is part of the data *model*. You should separate these two concepts in your code.

In your case, store the data in arrays (data model). When you want to display the data to user only then lay it out in divs or table html. Do the sorting before you lay out the html. When the user chooses sorting option from the dropdown, empty the `#contentContainer`, sort the array of data, regenerate html of newly ordered data and insert it into `#contentContainer`.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this and it worked fine for me. Youll just decide what you do with your array afterwards. :)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var priceItems = $('.price');
var arr = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < priceItems.length;i++) {
var tempInt = priceItems[i].innerHTML;
tempInt = parseInt(tempInt);
arr.push(tempInt);
}
arr.sort()  
});
```

All you now need, is use your array.