# Sorting Input Text inside multiple div's using javascript / jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, html, textbox

There are three fields(first name, Last name & age) displayed in text boxes. Each field is displayed in separate div's. There are 4 records. On clicking a sort button above each field the div records should be sorted based on the data type of the field and should displayed in the HTML page.

[I tried the solution in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10602817/sorting-of-div-data-using-jquery-or-javascript)

I can't use this because the records are displayed in text box within the div.

```
 <div id="content">
    <div>
      <div class="price"><input type="text" class="pri" value="120"/></div>
      <div class="dateDiv">2012-05-09 20:39:38.0</div>
      <div class="distance">20 mile</div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <div class="price"><input type="text" class="pri"  value="123"/></div>
      <div class="dateDiv">2012-05-10 20:39:38.0</div>
      <div class="distance">30 mile</div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class="price"><input type="text" class="pri" value="100" /></div>
      <div class="dateDiv">2012-05-11 20:39:38.0</div>
      <div class="distance">50 mile</div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <div class="price"><input type="text" class="pri" value="124"/></div>
      <div class="dateDiv">2012-05-12 20:39:38.0</div>
      <div class="distance">60 mile</div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

How can I do this in javascript?

Comment: can you give the javascript code what you have tried

Comment: Are you saying you want to sort the results based on the value of the input field? Also, why are you not sorting the data on the server side first rather than trying to sort in Javascript?

Comment: Please check your code above, your data is not consistent, is it fanme, lname, distance. OR price, datediv, distance?

Comment: @davidethell Yes. I've to sort the values in the input box which are inside div's. There is going to be lot of data, so posting the values to the server and again returning the sorted values back is going to be a huge process. And also whenever a new record is added the editor itself is going to sort the records.

Comment: @MishuCn
This is the code used in the above link I referred.
$('#content div.price').map(function () {
  // map sort-value and relevant dom-element for easier handling
  return {val: parseFloat($(this).text(), 10), el: this.parentNode};
}).sort(function (a, b) {
  // a simple asc-sort
  return a.val - b.val;
}).map(function () {
  // reduce the list to the actual dom-element
  return this.el;
}).appendTo('#content');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this demo using [jquery.tinysort.min.js](http://jsfiddle.net/WXZxG/)

see [also this one](http://jsfiddle.net/U8DPT/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com) to do something like that.

For example, the html:

```
<div id="content" data-bind="foreach: lines">
    <div class="fname"><input type="text class="pri" data-bind="value: fname"/></div>
    <div class="lname" data-bind="text: lname"/>
    <div class="age" data-bind="text: age"/>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function EachDivViewModel(line)
{
   this.fname = line.fname;
   this.lname = line.lname;
   this.age = line.age;
}

function YourViewModel()
{
   var self = this;
   self.lines = ko.observableArray([]); // this array will contain elements of EachDivViewModel type

   self.handlerForYourSortButtongs = function() {
      // Code here to sort the array based on the button clicked
      // The UI will automatically get updated as you reorder the elements in the lines array
   }
}


$(document).ready(function() {
   var yourViewModelInstance = new YourViewModel();
   // Code to get the lines here
   ko.applyBindings(yourViewModelInstance);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

It can be done using [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo).

Hope that will help you out.

Comment: Tablesorter doesn't really solve the problem because the OP is using DIVs not TABLEs.